# How to Check If a Value Already Exists in a Text Field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of users. Each time the `delete button` is click it is added up to the input text field which I already implemented. If the users is already on the `deleted_user` field, how can I display the remaining unselected users.

Ex. If Jan and Mike are already on `deleted_user` field. Next is clicking the `submit users button`, only Sam will appear

```
        <td><button onclick="deleteVal('Jan');" > Delete </button></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="users[]" value="Jan"> </td>

        <td><button onclick="deleteVal('Mike');"> Delete </button></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="users[]" value="Mike"> </td>

        <td><button onclick="deleteVal('Sam');"> Delete </button></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="users[]" value="Sam"> </td>


Deleted Users: <input type="text" id="deleted_user">

<button type="button" id="submit_users"> Submit Users </button> 
Final Users:<input type="text" id="final_users">
```

This is my code.

```
 function deleteVal(val) {
    var delete_id = val;
    var deleted_user = document.getElementById('deleted_user').value

    if(!deleted_user.includes(delete_id)) {
       var tempVal = document.getElementById('deleted_user').value += val + ',';    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you.

```js
var array_user = $("input[name='users[]']")
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

function deleteVal(val) {

  array_user = jQuery.grep(array_user, function(value) {
    return value != val;
  });

  var delete_id = val;
  var deleted_user = document.getElementById('deleted_user').value

  if (!deleted_user.includes(delete_id)) {
    var tempVal = document.getElementById('deleted_user').value += val + ',';
  }
  jQuery('#final_users').val(array_user.toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><button onclick="deleteVal('Jan');"> Delete </button></td>
<td><input type="text" name="users[]" value="Jan"> </td>

<td><button onclick="deleteVal('Mike');"> Delete </button></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="users[]" value="Mike"> </td>

<td><button onclick="deleteVal('Sam');"> Delete </button></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="users[]" value="Sam"> </td>


Deleted Users: <input type="text" id="deleted_user">

<button type="button" id="submit_users"> Submit Users </button> Final Users:<input type="text" id="final_users">
```

Comment: thank you sir. but would it be hard to check the fields exists on `deleted_users` before clicking the `submit` button? This is my code to populate the fields on `final_user` field. 



      `var users_value = [];
$('input[name="users[]"]').each(function() {
          users_value.push($(this).val());
      });
      if(users_value.length) {
        users_value = users_value.filter((a, b) => users_value.indexOf(a) === b); 
      }

      $(".modal-body #final_users").val(users_value);`

Comment: Can you use already used code var array_user = $("input[name='users[]']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
array_user = jQuery.grep(array_user, function(value) {
  return value != val;
});      
jQuery('#final_users').val(array_user.toString());

Comment: not gonna work sir, because it is only switching between the select and unselected names. so next is by clicking the submit, if the names already exist on `deleted_users` it will not appear on `final_users`. so I need to populate the `deleted_user field` first and then next is the `final_user field`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for check inputs fields

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        if(inputs[i]){
            alert("valid");
        }
        else{
            alert("not valid");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used pure Javascript:

```js
function deleteVal(val) {
 var delete_id = val;
    var deleted_user = document.getElementById('deleted_user').value;

    if(!deleted_user.includes(delete_id)) {
       var tempVal = document.getElementById('deleted_user').value += val + ',';
       for(var j=0; j<list.length; j++){
         if(list[j]==delete_id){
           list[j]=null;
            document.getElementById('final_users').value=list.join(" ");
          }
       }
    }   
  }
  var list=[];
 for(var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".names").length; i++){
  list[i] =document.querySelectorAll(".names")[i].value;
 }
document.getElementById('final_users').value=list.join(" ");

function checker(){
  for(k=0; k<list.length; k++){
    if(list[k]!=null){
      alert("There are remaining unselected users : "+list.join(" "));
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
        <td><button onclick="deleteVal('Jan');" > Delete </button></td>
        <td><input class="names" type="text" name="users[]" value="Jan"> </td>

        <td><button onclick="deleteVal('Mike');"> Delete </button></td>
        <td> <input class="names" type="text" name="users[]" value="Mike"> </td>

        <td><button onclick="deleteVal('Sam');"> Delete </button></td>
        <td> <input class="names" type="text" name="users[]" value="Sam"> </td>


Deleted Users: <input type="text" id="deleted_user">

<button onclick="checker()" type="button" id="submit_users"> Submit Users </button> 
Final Users:<input type="text" id="final_users">
```

That is what I understood.